# catch not being on route event in Backbone.Marionette

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

Is the a way to catch 'not being on partucular routes' event in Backbone.Marionette other then looking at window.location.href?

Edit: or catch module leave event

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a way to act on a route which doesn't have an assigned handler, then I don't think that it's possible. The Backbone history uses the loadUrl method which checks if there's some handler to use.
However, you can assign a catch-all route, something like: '/*': 'catchAll' as a last route, and then use it.